# Convert numeric to logical dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a presence/absence dataframe that's similar to this:

```
Cu Zn Mn
1  0  1 
0  0  1
1  0  1
0  1  1
```

I  want to convert it to a logical (TRUE/FALSE) dataframe. Is there anyway to do this? I've used the as.logical command, but the dataframe loses its structure. Additionally, I've tried replace, but it doesn't seem to work with a dataframe. Will anything convert the entire dataframe to logical values? Thanks!

Comment: Just do `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.logical)`

Comment: Just do `df1 == 1`

Comment: Using a matrix would be more appropriate (and faster) if you've got all numeric columns

Answer (score 6):

One option is to loop through the columns, convert it to `logical` and assign the output back to the object

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.logical)
```

Another option is creating a logical matrix

```
df1[] <- df1 >  0
```

Answer (score 3):

The tidyverse solution would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate_all(as.logical)
```

`mutate_all` walks over all columns and then applies its function .f argument, `as.logical`, to each column

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in R, but I do it like this and it works

```
df = !(!df)
```